# Parameter missing in rails controller which is not missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been recently learning ruby and rails in order to build a web application, so I have been following the starting out guide on the rails website.

I have got to a point where I am attempting to submit a form to my database, and rails is throwing this error:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in ArticlesController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: aritcle

Here is the code that it is refering to:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def new
end

private
def article_params
    params.require(:aritcle).permit(:title, :text)
end

public
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
end
```

end

What is interesting about this is that I had the code working ten minutes ago, exactly the same as it is now, but when I tried to tidy it up, it started throwing this error again, and when I put it back this way it didn't stop.

I have not seen this elsewhere, so would really appreciate any help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: You've misspelled `article` in your `params.require...` call in `article_params`.

Comment: so, first off, a good practice is to put your public methods at the top, and then use the 'private' word to declare your private methods. About your question, looks like no 'article' hash is being passed to the controller. With that said, it would be good if you include in your question your template, and maybe the rails log to see what it is receiving in the request.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, and I cannot believe that I didn't see that misspelling. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code after taking @Jake Shorty and @fanta into consideration.  Fixing the typo and re-arranging the code.

The advantage to using the `private` keyword is that the method order no longer matters.  No chance of accidentally making a method private or public when you meant the other one.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
  private :article_params

end
```